# Trying to use a batch file to work with filenames that have a forbidden character

Tags: batch-file

Okay, a brief explanation of what I am doing: I use Windows Media Center (Windows 7) to record Jeopardy every evening. I then use Handbrake to convert the .wtv files to .mkv files and then transfer them to my NAS so I can watch them later using Plex Media Server/Center. Rather than doing this "by hand", I'm trying to automate the process using a batch file as a scheduled task. Initially, I had set up a script so that I could right-click > Send To > convert.bat and it would initiate the command-line interface for Handbrake and convert the file, move the output to my NAS, and delete the original file (worked great).

Now, what I'm doing is initiating the batch script as a scheduled task and looping through the contents of my "recorded tv" directory and looping through any .wtv files to convert/move/delete them.

The problem lies in the fact that Windows Media Center correctly names the Jeopardy files with the "!" in them (Eg: Jeopardy!_KHQ_2012_12_04_21_12_12.wtv), which completely bricks my script. The "Send To" batch file worked great, but when I loop through the *.wtv files in the directory, it returns all the filenames with the "!" stripped out which means I can't do squat with them. Files without "!" do process without a hitch.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can get me pointed in the right direction! (and if you happen to see any other areas where this script could be improved, that's fine too...)

Here is the basic code that I am attempting to use:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET count=0
SET getFolder=C:\Users\Public\Recorded TV\
SET ripFolder=C:\Rips\
SET putFolder=Z:\Videos\Recorded TV\

FOR %%F IN ("%getFolder%*.wtv") DO (
SET /A count=!count!+1

REM DETERMINE OUTPUT FILENAME
for /f "tokens=5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=\_" %%a in ("%%F") do (
    set show=%%a
    set station=%%b
    set year=%%c
    set month=%%d
    set day=%%e
    set hour=%%f

    REM GENERATE OUTPUT NAMING CONVENTION   
    set output=!show! s!year!e!month!!day! !hour!

)

REM PROCESS WITH HANDBRAKE CLI
"C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i "%%F" -t 1 -c 1 -o %ripFolder%!OUTPUT!.mkv  -f mkv --deinterlace="fast" --crop 58:60:2:2 --strict-anamorphic  -e x264 -q 20 --vfr  -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0 --gain=0 --audio-copy-mask none --audio-fallback ffac3 -x ref=1:weightp=1:subq=2:rc-lookahead=10:trellis=0:8x8dct=0 --verbose=1

REM MOVE CONVERTED FILE TO NAS
copy "%ripFolder%!OUTPUT!.mkv" "%putFolder%"

REM DELETE ORIGINAL
del "%%F"

REM DELETE LOCAL RIP
del "%ripFolder%!output!.mkv"
)

echo %count% files processed

pause

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: There is a way to escape the "!" char.  Its something like ^!! or ^^! or !! or something like that.  Play around... you will figure it out.

Comment: I'm aware of how to escape a character. The problem is that the character that needs to be escaped is stripped out before I can do anything with it. Some vague advice followed by "play around, you'll figure it out" isn't exactly helpful. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you but you could have also presented your question in a way that is easier for us to reproduce.  if that were the case I would have been more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As you have recognized, the exclamation mark is stripped before you can escape it.
That's because you expand the FOR-loop variable `%%F` while delayed expansion is enabled, and the exclamation mark tries to expand a variable.

You need to toggle the delayed expansion here, as the variable contents are safe when using with delayed expansion, but to get the value you need the disabled mode.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
SET count=0

FOR %%F IN ("%getFolder%*.wtv") DO (
  set "orgFile=%%F"
  SET /A count+=1

  REM DETERMINE OUTPUT FILENAME
  for /f "tokens=5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=\_" %%a in ("%%F") do (
    set show=%%a
    set station=%%b
    set year=%%c
    set month=%%d
    set day=%%e
    set hour=%%f

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    REM GENERATE OUTPUT NAMING CONVENTION   
    set output=!show! s!year!e!month!!day! !hour!
  )
  REM PROCESS WITH HANDBRAKE CLI
  "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i "%%F" -t 1 -c 1 -o %ripFolder%!OUTPUT!.mkv  -f mkv --deinterlace="fast" --crop 58:60:2:2 --strict-anamorphic  -e x264 -q 20 --vfr  -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0 --gain=0 --audio-copy-mask none --audio-fallback ffac3 -x ref=1:weightp=1:subq=2:rc-lookahead=10:trellis=0:8x8dct=0 --verbose=1

  REM MOVE CONVERTED FILE TO NAS
  copy "%ripFolder%!OUTPUT!.mkv" "%putFolder%"

  REM DELETE ORIGINAL
  del "!orgFile!"

  REM DELETE LOCAL RIP
  del "%ripFolder%!output!.mkv"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a very clunky work-around just to get it running, but this is a much cleaner solution, will give it a try!

Comment: Can't you do the same thing (without disabling delayed expansion) by using "set orgFile=!!F".  It would be easy to try.  If it works: awesome, otherwise: use the method in this answer.